# Can't figure out why my second count variable isn't counting PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, while-loop, nested

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    v_ans        testloop.ctr%TYPE := 0;
    v_ct         testloop.rec_no%TYPE := 1;
    v_ans1       NUMBER := 0;
    v_ctin       NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    WHILE v_ct < 5 LOOP
        WHILE v_ctin < 5 LOOP
            v_ans := v_ct + v_ctin;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_ct || ' + ' || v_ctin || ' = ' || v_ans);
            v_ctin := v_ctin + 1;
        END LOOP;
        v_ct := v_ct + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why?
If it isn't clear, I'm just trying to have an output like this:

1+1 = 2, 1 + 2 = 3, 1 + 3 = 4, 2 + 1 = 3 etc

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the variable in the outer loop:

```
BEGIN
   WHILE v_ct < 5 LOOP
        v_ctin := 1;
--------^
        WHILE v_ctin < 5 LOOP
             v_ans := v_ct + v_ctin;
                dbms_output.put_line(v_ct || ' + ' || v_ctin || ' = ' || v_ans);
         v_ctin := v_ctin + 1;
        END LOOP;
    v_ct := v_ct + 1;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, that did it. Question, why would i re-initialize that?

Comment: @user7823016 - If you don't reset the second counter to 1 for each iteration of the outer loop, what will set it back to 1? In each iteration of the inner loop you simply increase it by 1; if you don't reset it when the outer loop moves on to the next iteration, the second counter would keep increasing (but you have a condition on it for the inner loop, so no further iterations actually go through).